# python, sorting a list by a key that's a substring of each element

Tags: python, list, sorting

Part of a programme builds this list,

```
[u'1 x Affinity for war', u'1 x Intellect', u'2 x Charisma', u'2 x Perception', u'3 x Population growth', u'4 x Affinity for the land', u'5 x Morale']
```

I'm currently trying to sort it alphabetically by the name of the evolution rather than by the number. Is there any way I can do this without just changing the order the two things appear in the list (as in 'intellect x 1)?

Comment: As a side note, you may find it more convenient in general if you convert that to a list of tuples rather than unicode strings; in particular named tuples may really help code readability.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to get the "key" from the string.

```
def myKeyFunc( aString ):
    stuff, x, label = aString.partition(' x ')
    return label

aList.sort( key= myKeyFunc )
```

Comment: Precisely and exactly what is says.  That is just "stuff".  "miscellaneous unspecified objects" according to a Thesaurus.  The partition method of a string returns three results.  One of those is just "stuff" that's never used again.

Comment: In this context, the stuff in front of the " x " might be meaningful, but we can't tell from the question what it is or what it means.  Since the question is vague, we can only call it "stuff".

Comment: Did you know that you can use underscores for parts of the tuple that you won't use: `_,_,label = aString.partition(' x ')`

Comment: @Amoss: Some folks don't like it and prefer "real" variable names.  Some folks prefer the `_`.

Answer (score 11):

How about:

```
lst.sort(key=lamdba s: s.split(' x ')[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing if your items are standardized at 1 digit, 1 space, 1 'x', 1 space, multiple words I wrote this up:

```
mylist = [u'1 x Affinity for war', u'1 x Intellect', u'2 x Charisma', u'2 x Perception', u'3 x Population growth', u'4 x Affinity for the land', u'5 x Morale']
def sort(a, b):
  return cmp(" ".join(a.split()[2:]), " ".join(b.split()[2:]))

mylist.sort(sort)
```

You can edit the parsing inside the `sort` method but you probably get the idea.

Cheers,
Patrick

Comment: Better to use key= than a custom comparator when you can because a custom comparator must be called n*log n times, but the key function only needs n calls.

Answer (score 1):

To do so, you need to implement a custom compare:

```
def myCompare(x, y):
   x_name = " ".join(x.split()[2:])
   y_name = " ".join(y.split()[2:])
   return cmp(x_name, y_name)
```

Then you use that compare definition as the input to your sort function:

```
myList.sort(myCompare)
```

Answer (score -10):

As you are trying to sort what is essentially custom data, I'd go with a custom sort.

[Merge sort](http://en.literateprograms.org/Merge_sort_(Python))
[Bubble sort](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/index.php?title=Bubble_sort#Python)
[Quicksort](http://en.literateprograms.org/Quicksort_(Python,_arrays))

Comment: No, you want to use the built-in sorting method with a custom comparator.

Comment: Is that what S.Lott has done? If not, would you be able to share a code example?

Comment: This a terrible suggestion. He's trying to get something to sort, not to implement a sort. There is a big difference. One is useful and one is a waste of time.

Comment: Yes, absolutely do not reinvent the wheel by writing a custom sort. Huge waste of time.