# python - sorting a list of lists by a key that's substring of each element

Tags: python, list, sorting, date

I have a list like this:

```
[('Cat\nDiff. le 07/01/15 à 11:00', var1, var2),
 ('Dog\nDiff. le 06/01/15 à 10:55', var3, var4),
 ('Fish\nDiff. le 03/01/15 à 09:15', var5, var6)]
```

I would like to sort this list by date, to have:

```
[('Fish\nDiff. le 03/01/15 à 09:15', var5, var6),
('Dog\nDiff. le 06/01/15 à 10:55', var3, var4),
('Cat\nDiff. le 07/01/15 à 11:00', var1, var2)]
```

I've seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440541/python-sorting-a-list-by-a-key-thats-a-substring-of-each-element) and the first solution works with a simple list, but I can't find a way to use it for a list of lists.

How can I do? Thanks.

Comment: Will the date be always after two space separated words?

Comment: yes, the format will be always like this. I would like to sort it by hours, too...

Comment: your first step is to figure out how to actually compare 2 items. So, you need to figure out how to extract a date object for a given item. Then it is simply a matter of using that in a sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the key for comparing 2 elements:

```
import time
def key(item):
    return time.strptime(item[0][-16:], "%d/%m/%y à %H:%M")
```

Then sort it:

```
print sorted(my_list,key=key)
```

Comment: Thanks, after several attemps I have tried your code ans it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

```
l =[('Cat\nDiff. le 07/01/15 à 11:00',"var1", "var2"),
    ('Cat\nDiff. le 07/01/15 à 10:00',"var3","var4"),
 ('Dog\nDiff. le 06/01/15 à 10:55',"var5","var6"),
 ('Fish\nDiff. le 03/01/15 à 09:15',"var7","var8")]
```

use datetime objects:

```
from datetime import datetime
def srt(x):
    spl = x[0].split()
    return datetime.strptime("{} {}".format(spl[3],spl[-1]),"%d/%m/%y %H:%M")

print(sorted(l,key=srt))
[('Fish\nDiff. le 03/01/15 \xc3\xa0 09:15', 'var7', 'var8'), ('Dog\nDiff. le 06/01/15 \xc3\xa0 10:55', 'var5', 'var6'), ('Cat\nDiff. le 07/01/15 \xc3\xa0 10:00', 'var3', 'var4'), ('Cat\nDiff. le 07/01/15 \xc3\xa0 11:00', 'var1', 'var2')]
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried your solution but with a big list, the sort don't work. I will try with datetime. Thanks again to help me :)

Comment: @Guillaume, the datetime objects will work once your list is like you have posted

Comment: I understand, but I can't post the real list, to much complicate. Anyway, I will try to use your answer and adapt my code. Thanks again

Comment: @Guillaume, no worries, all you have to do is make sure you are passing in the correct parameters to datetime. You must use datetime objects as just sorting will not work as suggested in another answer, it would put la before le even if the date was after.

Comment: The njzk2's code works perfectly! :p

Comment: @Guillaume, the code does exactly the same thing mine does, the reason I use split is that indexing will break if you happen to have an extra space.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose if the solution you referenced works as you intend, it should be trivial to use it modified in such a manner:

```
def myKeyFunc( subList ):
    stuff, x, label = subList[0].partition(' x ')
    return label

aList.sort( key= myKeyFunc )
```

I would caution against this though - it seems it may be better to first sanitize those sub-lists to more friendly data formats (i.e. parse them first, and extract the date into an additional usable item of the sublist) For example, you might want to turn this:

```
('Cat\nDiff. le 07/01/15 à 11:00', var1, var2)
```

Into this:

```
('Cat\nDiff. le 07/01/15 à 11:00', var1, var2, DateObject)
```

Comment: you're right, I'm i little tired !

Comment: this only works because the dates happen to align with the names, it does not sort by date at all change `le` to `la`